# xml data is not displaying in web service

Tags: c#, web-services

This is my xml output of service.

```
<LifeAreas>
    <Overall i:nil="true"/>
    <Career>
        <Good>
            <NamePlanet/>
            <NamePlanet/>
        </Good>
        <Neutral>
            <NamePlanet/>
            <NamePlanet/>
            <NamePlanet/>
        </Neutral>
        <Bad>
             <NamePlanet/>
             <NamePlanet/>
             <NamePlanet/>
             <NamePlanet/>
        </Bad>
   </Career>
   <Finance i:nil="true"/>
   <Relationship i:nil="true"/>
   <Health i:nil="true"/>
```

DataContract used are below:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Areas", Namespace = "")] 
public sealed class Areas
{ 
    [DataMember(Name = "Overall", Order = 0)]
    public PlanetDiginity Overall { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Career", Order = 1)]
    public PlanetDiginity Career { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Finance", Order = 2)]
    public PlanetDiginity Finance { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Relationship", Order = 3)]
    public PlanetDiginity Relationship { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Health", Order = 4)]
    public PlanetDiginity Health { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name = "NamePlanet", Namespace = "")]  
public sealed class NamePlanet
{
    public string PlanetName { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name = "PlanetDiginity", Namespace = "")] 
public sealed class PlanetDiginity
{
    ///<summary>
    /// Gets and Sets the Planet Diginity
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Name = "Good", Order = 0)]
    public List<NamePlanet> Good { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Neutral", Order = 1)]
    public List<NamePlanet> Neutral { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Bad", Order = 2)]
    public List<NamePlanet> Bad { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name = "GoodBadPlanetList", Namespace = "")]
public sealed class GoodBadPlanetList
{
    [DataMember(Name = "GoodBadPlanetReport", Order = 2)]
    public List<GoodBadPlanetReport> GoodBadPlanetReport { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "AstroDetails", Order = 0)]
    public AstroInfo AstroDetails { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "LifeAreas", Order = 1)]
    public Areas LifeAreas { get; set; }
}
```

From web service the required data is coming in the node of  but in the xml it is not displaying. Only it is displaying the property name as many times as in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the PlanetName property of the NamePlanet class is missing the DataMember attribute

Comment: Yes, you are right. However I came to know before reading your answer.
Thanks a lot.